# Can I change a value of an existing anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I am creating an anonymous object like so:

```
var myObj = new { ownerId = string.Empty, dateFrom = dateFrom, dateTo = dateTo };
```

And then, later on in the code (after some other logic) I am *trying* to assign something different to the `ownerId`:

```
myObj.ownerId = accountRec.RingCentralOwnerId;
```

But I get the error

> Property or indexer '...ownerId' cannot be assigned to -- it is read
>   only

Is there any way I can assign a new value to a property of an anonymous type after it's been created?

Comment: No; they're immutable.

Comment: It's the official way:"If you don't wanna name and type it, who are you to change it? You don't know them, They don't know you." that's what we used to say.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know.